# Django - FilerFileField direct upload

Tags: python, django

In my django-project, there is a book model, where you can append a pdf.

```
class Product(CategoryProductBase):
    book = FilerFileField( verbose_name=_("Book"),)
    description = HTMLField(null=True,blank=True)
```

my form:

```
class UploadBookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    book = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=filer.models.File.objects.all(),label=u"Buch als PDF")
    description = forms.CharField(label=u"Kurzbeschreibung")
```

I used ModelChoiceField there, but how can I use a FileField? I want the PDF to upload to the filer from django filer egg. I want it to save in a folder named 'Book'.